The compressionMinSize configuration in Tomcat 7 is no longer functional
I would like to ask why compressionMinSize=2048 has been configured in tomcat7, but it has not taken effect and will cause the memory of my server to continue to be on the high side. Can I ask what the solution is ?enter image description here
Am I missing any hidden setting?
But all its requesenter image description herets are also compressed
